# Why does write file binary method sometimes return a letter and other an hex?

Tags: python-3.x, file, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a bmp file.
I get diferent notations on the bytes I read.
I would like to understand why the "read" method acts this way.

For that purpose:
- I open the file in binary read mode.
- I create an empty list.
- I go through the binary file reading it byte by byte.
- Each time I read a byte I load it in the list.

- When I go over the list I obtain shaking results.
- Sometimes I get a binary "letter", like b'B'.
- Others I get a binary hex, like 0x38.

Why does it acts sometimes in a way and others in a different way?
Why doesn't it always return an hex?

def main():

```
fichero = open("C:\\Users\\gsanmar\\Pictures\\astilleros-ferrol.bmp", "rb")

bytesDelFichero = []
for i in range(0,70):
    bytesDelFichero.append(fichero.read(1))

for valor in bytesDelFichero:
    print(valor)
```

main()

Actual results are:

b'B'
b'M'
b'\xf6'
b'i'
b'0'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'6'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'('
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'@'
b'\x06'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x95'
b'\x02'
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how bytes are printed - if they're printable characters (letters, numbers...), you will see them in output instead of hex codes.

If you want hex codes everywhere, do something like:

```py
for valor in bytesDelFichero:
    print(hex(int(valor)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much truth. But that doesn't work in Python 3.7. When it tries to convert the printable characters it gets an exception:  bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Anyway thank you.

Comment: oops! `hex(int(value))` should work.  I'll edit my answer.